# Neural net gave me this formula - is it related to any mathematical series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, power-series, taylor-expansion

I was working on a new type of neural net, and in the process came up with an equation that looks familiar:

> -ab + b + a – a(b^2) – (a^2)b + (a^2) * (b^2)

It is symmetric, and it looks like I should remember it from college math.  But I don't.  Is this an arbitrary equation or does it have application elsewhere?

It is an expression for an activation function for a neural net node that takes in 2 inputs, a and b.

Comment: there is no equation over there it is just an expression

Comment: it is not an equation an "=" is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it Can be written as $$\left( ab-1 \right)  \left( ab-a-b \right) $$